# select each file in zip file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I want to write a Local API with `Node.JS` that I pass a Local zip file path to it, like `"C:/Users/mansour/Desktop/Training/app.zip"`
after that, I have to check the zip file recursively and if there is a file or files with `".mogrt"` extension then I run a function with that files.
i wrote some code but I can't complete this.

```
const extractZipFile = (mogrtUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const zip = new AdmZip(mogrtUrl);
    zip.getEntries().forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.name.split('.').pop() === 'mogrt') {
        resolve({
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': '',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000'
          },
          contents: []
        });
      }
    })
  });
}
```

I'm not using express.

I'm Using "adm-zip" node package.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "can't complete this".  It looks like you're partially there and seem to be correctly using adm-zip.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: @JimB.i mean can't complete the code! actually, I have a problem with node resolve thing. what I have to pass in there? I'm a newbie with Node!

Comment: The rule of promises is you must resolve or reject, and only once.  Unresolved promises effectively hang the code that may be waiting for them.  Your current implementation only resolves if the entry name ends in '.mogrt', but it also looks like it would resolve multiple times if multiple entries match.  Maybe describe what your function is supposed to be doing, and take another crack at the code?

Comment: @JimB. for each 'mogrt' file, my function will import the file into adobe premier extension. I just want the API to send an array of 'mogrt' files as a response that my function will do rest of the job!

Comment: Why are you trying to use a promise here?  It looks like these functions are synchronous.

Comment: @JimB. don't know!!! what can I do instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your input file, so you'll have to debug this yourself.

This function should return a list of objects for which the entry name matches '.mogrt':

```
const extractZipFile = mogrtUrl => {
    const zip = new AdmZip(mogrtUrl);
    return zip.getEntries().reduce((list, entry) => {
        if (entry.name.split('.').pop() === 'mogrt') {
            list.push({
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': '',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000'
                },
                contents: []
            });
        }
        return list;
    }, []);
};
```

This works synchronously, which may be ok depending on your application.  If this process takes too long due to very large files, you might consider an asynchronous approach to process the zip file.